# Python: file.readline() jumping previous line on a file

Tags: python

I want to recover this four lines tagged ERROR, contained in a file:

```
ERROR    Blablabalbalablabalbalablabalbalablabalbalablabalbalablabalbala
ERROR    Tototototototototototototototototototototototototototototototot
ERROR    Hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
         hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
ERROR    Lalalalalalalalala
```

```
    def getErrorWarningInfo(self, file, line, tag):
        msg = line.strip(tag)
        while True:
            nextline = file.readline()
            if ('         ' in nextline):
                msg += "\n"+nextline.strip()
            break
        return [self.id, tag, msg] ,line
```

I recover only 3 ERROR including the one containing two lines, but I can't get the line before this one:

```
ERROR    Tototototototototototototototototototototototototototototototot
```

And when I remove, in the function, the line `file.readline()`, I recover the **4 ERROR but only the first line of the one with two lines**.

Comment: you probably should use str.startswith("             ") instead of `in` - you might want to set a bool flag to True if you detect a line starting with "ERROR" and only set it to False when your line does not also start with either "ERROR" or "               ". To get help, try formulating a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Why don't You use `file.read().split('ERROR')` and then  remove whitespaces? (:

Answer (score 0):

Here is a prototype to get around your issue. You can adjust it for your need if you like it.
I've edited a log file to contain INFO and WARNING too

```
ERROR    Blablabalbalablabalbalablabalbalablabalbalablabalbalablabalbala
ERROR    Tototototototototototototototototototototototototototototototot
INFO     tik tok
ERROR    Hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
         hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
WARNING  bip bup
ERROR    Lalalalalalalalala
```

```
    # types of tags you can encounter in log
    TAGS = ["ERROR", "INFO", "WARNING"]
    LOG = "./LOG"
    with open(LOG) as log:
        lines = []
        # you want to keep previous line in case next line is continuation of it
        prev_line = ""
        for line in log.readlines():
            # Check if line contains any tags
            if any(map(line.__contains__, TAGS)):
                if prev_line:
                    # If we already have a previous line, we can add it to the list. 
                    # The current line also contains a tag
                    lines.append(prev_line)
                # Current line becomes previous
                prev_line = line
                continue
            # If there is no tag in the line, it most be continuation of previous.
            prev_line += line
    
    # Check that all lines concatenated correctly
    for line in lines:
        print line
    
    print("============ Filtering logs  =============\n")
    # Now you can filter your lines by log tags
    def get_errors(lines):
        return [line for line in lines if "ERROR" in line]
    
    # Only ERROR logs 
    for line in get_errors(lines):
        print line
```

Outputs

```
ERROR    Blablabalbalablabalbalablabalbalablabalbalablabalbalablabalbala

ERROR    Tototototototototototototototototototototototototototototototot

INFO     tik tok

ERROR    Hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
         hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi

WARNING  bip bup

============ Filtering logs  =============

ERROR    Blablabalbalablabalbalablabalbalablabalbalablabalbalablabalbala

ERROR    Tototototototototototototototototototototototototototototototot

ERROR    Hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
         hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

I think that the problem comes from the main function, when I read my file and call this function "getErrorWarningInfo()" to analyse each line.
```
def parse_file(f):
    for line in f:
          if (line.startswith("ERROR")):
                error, line = self.getErrorWarningInfo(f, line, "ERROR")
          [...]
```
The cursor moves forward in the main function, and when this function is called, it continues to move forward. Do you have a way to solve this problem, if this is the case?

Comment: Hi @Nouna, can you edit your question to have a better picture of the problem? I thought the problem was to get a whole log because it spans across multiple lines.

Comment: Hi @propabuzz! Thank you for helping me!

I think that the problem comes from the main function, when I read my file, line by line (with a loop) and call this function "getErrorWarningInfo()" to analyse each line: **the cursor (line number) moves forward in the main function, and when this function is called, it continues to move forward.** I think that's why it jumped the second ERROR, don't you think so?

_I hope that you will understand what I'm trying to explain._

Comment: @Nouna you probably call readline() twice then. First time to pass line to a function and then in the function. I'm not sure. Share the main function or at least part of it where you read the file.

Comment: @Nouna, I've tried to execute what you have and I'm getting the following error from the compiler:
nextline = file.readline()
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data. I think you better use methods provided by file module rather than looping yourself. See the example I gave you. My advice would be to organize lines first, then filter and do whatever else you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse_file(self):
        for file in self.prt_files:
            with open(os.path.join(self.path, file), "r") as f:
                try:
                    for line in f:
                        if (line.startswith("ERROR")):
                            error, line = self.getErrorWarningInfo(f, line, "ERROR")

[...]
```